# No module named 'pyomo.environ'

Tags: python, pip, pyomo

I'm trying to use Pyomo for solving optimization problems. I'm trying to run the following piece of code

```
import pyomo.environ as pyo

model = pyo.AbstractModel()


model.n = pyo.Param(within=pyo.NonNegativeIntegers)

model.I = pyo.RangeSet(1, model.m)
```

but I get the following error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyomo.environ'; 'pyomo' is not a package
```

im not sure whats causing this as i have followed the installation instructions on the pyomo documentation website. I've installed pyomo using pip

```
pip install pyomo
```

and i also tried using the conda environment by installing pyomo there and running the script from conda but got same error. Im not sure what pyomo.environ is but i tried running the following pip call `pip install pyomo.environ` but got an error that no such package exists.

anyone know why im missing this module? isn't pyomo.environ supposed to be part of the pyomo package, if not how am i supposed to install it?

Comment: "*'pyomo' is not a package*" Any chance you run this from a script named `pyomo.py`? May be there is a subdirectory `pyomo/` in the current directory?

Comment: yes, that was the case, the file name was pyomo.py. renaming the file fixed the issue. thanks

Answer (score 1):

a comment suggested that the problem was a naming issue. the file name was the same name as the package, renaming the file fixed the problem

Comment: Never call you script the same name as importable package. Avoid names that overshadow standard libraries. Don't name your scripts `email.py`, `test.py`, etc.